# Object setter of the target type is not called when casting an object into the specific type

Tags: typescript

Assume a class of the following type:

```
class Person {
  private _firstName: string;

  get FirstName(): string { return this._firstName; }
  set FirstName(firstName: string) { this._firstName = firstName; }
}
```

After calling `HttpClient.get<Person>()` it returns an object of type `Person` but it does not call the setter of that objects properties.

Example showing the issue that a cast does not call the setter but a normal object creation does:
https://jsfiddle.net/r175sLkh/

The reason behind this seems to be the fact that upon converting from JSON string an anonymous object is generated and then casted into the desired object. When there is a setter for a Property it will be overwritten with the simple type from the JSON object.

Original `Person.FirstName()` will be overwritten by `(anonymous).FirstName` because of the same name.

So to actually get my setter in action i would have to iterate over the result from `HttpClient.get<Person>()` and assign it manually property by property into a newly created `Person` object…

So my question now…

Is there a *better* way to make sure that a setter is honored when casting into the desired object other than manually converting/assigning them? (This question is not about getter/setter in general in TypeScript.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your first mistake is in you assumptions about execution time. Typescript only provides compile time type safety and it does not work like other type save languages like java or c#. Those types are not enforced. And expression like `HttpClient.get<Person>()` is not forcing Person instance to be returned it just states that you assume it will return object compliant with Person class nothing more. There is no casting of anonymous object to Person object just the deserialized object is returned.

So given that there is no way to enforce setter to be executed, other than explicit code that does it.

Comment: That is a good point. Totally overlooked the fact that it's only a "layer" on top of "objects". I wonder if i could make an own cast that will actually convert an object.